# mySQL DATE with CONCAT Date and Time not working

Tags: mysql, date, concatenation

I have within the database two columns, one eDate and the other eTime.  I am trying to get it so within a mySQL query, I can join them to make a whole DATETIME which, combined, result in records only after NOW().

Here is the data image:
[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
      (SELECT count(*) FROM aw_event_attendees AS attendees WHERE events.eid = attendees.eid) AS allattending,
      (SELECT count(*) FROM aw_event_attendees AS attendees WHERE events.eid = attendees.eid AND attendees.uid = " . $_POST['uid']. " ) AS attending
FROM aw_events as events WHERE DATE(CONCAT(eDate, ' ', eTime)) >= NOW() ORDER BY events.eid DESC";
```

And this is the result I am getting:

[image]

It is missing todays, 23-2-2015 @ 21:30.  I cannot seem to make it realise the time.   Any suggestions please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest storing the objects as DATETIME objects and splitting them out where needed, rather than splitting them and trying to join.

An event has a specific DATETIME that it begins, so that's the correct data type.

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible, as the data is already there.  But their must be a way I can combine the two ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing the code to this:

```
SELECT *,
      (SELECT count(*) FROM aw_event_attendees AS attendees WHERE events.eid = attendees.eid) AS allattending,
      (SELECT count(*) FROM aw_event_attendees AS attendees WHERE events.eid = attendees.eid AND attendees.uid = 35) AS attending
FROM aw_events as events WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(eDate, ' ', eTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > NOW() ORDER BY events.eid DESC
```

The change of the code is as follows:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(eDate, ' ', eTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

The results give the date, and time, only after `NOW()` including if the date is the same:

[image]

Job done!  Hope it helps others :)